# Can't move object down in y axis - Raphael, Javascript, SVG

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael, vector-graphics

I am having trouble moving an image down in an SVG animation

Using the animate() function I first move the image up which works fine:

```
greenBar1.animate({y: 200}, 200, 'elastic');
```

But I then try to move it back down by changing the y value but it only pushes it up further:
I have tried:

```
greenBar1.animate({y:'-50'}, 200, 'elastic');
```

and

```
greenBar1.animate({y:'.50'}, 200, 'elastic');
```

both with and without the quotes but they both move the image up

Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to be certain without complete reference code, but I'm willing to lay a wager that the issue comes down to a misunderstanding of the difference between coordinate attributes and transforms.  When you animate an image's x or y attributes, Raphael will use those absolute values -- and of course, -50 and .5 are both "above" 200 in the coordinate systems of both the screen and the SVG object.  If you want to use animate in such a way that the object's position is modified relative to its starting position (which is what you appear to be doing), try this instead:

```
greenBar1.animate(  { transform: [ "T", 0, -100 ] }, 200, 'elastic', 
                    function()
                    {
                        // note that the callback is invoked in the context of the animated element, so we can simply write...
                        this.animate( { transform: "" }, 200, 'elastic' );
                    } );
```

Instead of changing the fundamental coordinates of the element, you can instruct the SVG to transform it, first up 100 units from its starting position, and then back "down" to its original position (this being accomplished by clearing the transform attribute).

Raphael's [documentation on transformations](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform) is lamentably terse, but you might find some interesting material there.

If this doesn't solve your problem, please post a fiddle or some other snapshot of the malfunctioning code.